# Math is Awesome

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, alphametic

I have a shirt.
[image]
It says that $AWE+SOME=MATH.$ A, W, E, S, O, T, M, and H are not necessarily distinct positive integers from $0$ to $9$. The goal is to find the maximum possible value of $MATH.$

If you are wondering where I got it, I got this shirt from participating in an AWESOMEMATH summer camp.

Comment: A cryptarithm solver shows 106 possible solutions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Trivial solution without distinct values:

> 904 + 9094 = 9998

Maximizing MATH with distinct values:

> If we try M=9, S=8, we need a carry from 1+O+A=10+A. This need O=9, which isn't available.
>  So we let M=8, S=7 and O=9. The largest value available for A is 6, then W is at most 5. Finally, to avoid duplicate values we find E=2 and H=4.
>  652 + 7982 = 8634

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I wouldn't just simply say that it's trivial. I think this answer would improve if you explained the steps to get the trivial solution.

Comment: E+E in the last digits of AWE+SOME means MATH is even. The highest even 4-digit number is 9998. That's why Daniel put it as trivial.

Comment: Since they don't have to be integers can E be 5-epsilon and then the max is 10000-2*epsilon. Its a bit weird for these kinds of puzzles but given the question explicitly says they don't have to be distinct positive *integers* it seems that considering non-integers is fair...

Comment: @Chris that's a lateral thinking reading of the question, haha. Nice one. Probably better phrased as "positive integers, not necessarily distinct"

Comment: Honestly I didn't think that was any more lateral thinking than that they didn't have to be distinct. In these sorts of puzzles I have never seen the letters not be distinct (though I may not have a large dataset to work with) so I didn't think them not being integers was any weirder than them not being distinct.

Comment: @Chris Extending that logic, though, there is no maximum at all, since E could be a complex number and there is no total order over the complex numbers.

Comment: Except that the question declares there is a maximum to find which means that we can't be considering complex numbers. Otherwise I'd be more than happy for you to extend the logic that way if you wanted! I will note though that my comment was just an amusing consideration. If I thought it was actually a serious response to the question I'd have added it as an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 11):

Explaining the "trivial solution" mentioned by Daniel

The last digit cannot be 9 because it is `2 * E` (from AW**E** and SOM**E**) , therefore needs to be even. That leads to `9998` as possible max value for `MATH` and `E = 4` as only possible value for `E`. Let's try:

```
    A W 4
+ S O M 4
---------
  9 9 9 8
```

As we want to have `M = 9` (from **M**ATH), we can conclude that `W = 0` because `W + M = 9` (and we have no carry over from the first digit).

```
    A 0 4
+ S O 9 4
---------
  9 9 9 8
```

We also want to have `A = 9` (from M**A**TH), we again can conclude that `O = 0` because `A + 0 = 9` (and again no carry over)

```
    9 0 4
+ S 0 9 4
---------
  9 9 9 8
```

Leaves us with `S = 9` to reach the final result.

```
    9 0 4
+ 9 0 9 4
---------
  9 9 9 8
```

**Upate**
As quarage pointed out, there is another possible solution for 9998, and it's also straight forward. The assumption that 9999 is not possible is still valid, but of course you can reach `H = 8` (for MAT**H**) also with `E = 9`:

```
    A W 9
+ S O M 9
      1 
---------
  9 9 9 8
```

As we know that `M = 9` (from **M**ATH) and now we have a carry over from the first digit, we know that `W = 9`:

```
    A 9 9
+ S O 9 9
    1 1 
---------
  9 9 9 8
```

And we know that `A = 9` (from M**A**TH), so `O = 9`

```
    9 9 9
+ S 9 9 9
  1 1 1 
---------
  9 9 9 8
```

Which finally leads to `S = 8`

```
    9 9 9
+ 8 9 9 9
  1 1 1 
---------
  9 9 9 8
```

Comment: Note that E=9 is also possible to achieve the H=8 but I think that leads to a contradiction further down the line.

Comment: @quarague I don't think so, 999 + 8999 = 9998, with E=9, M=9 and A=9 in all cases

Answer (score 7):

A much nicer version of the trivial answer that is already noted is

> M = 8 and H = 8 and everything else = 9.
>
>  This gives 8999+999 = 9998 a lovely almost palindromic equation (though I did have to rearrange the numbers a bit.

Comment: I like this one

Answer (score 5):

Everyone's assuming

> that $AWE$, $SOME$, and $MATH$ are formed by concatenating the single-digit integers of $A$, $W$, etc.

But

> this is a math equation, and ordinarily $xy$ means $x$ times $y$, not $10x+y$.

Which means that the maximum *potential* value of $MATH$ is

> $9^4=6561$, achieved when $M=A=T=H=9$.

Can we achieve this?

> Sure! With some quick algebra, the equation becomes $9WE+9SOE=9^4$, which we can simplify to $E(W+SO)=9^3$. Speculatively plugging in $E=9$, we get $W+SO=81$, which is achievable with $W=S=9$ and $O=8$.

Incidentally,

> Note that the question (as currently posted) does not limit $M$ to an integer between 0 and 9.

If we exploit this loophole,

> we can set $A=E=S=O=T=H=1$ and $W=0$ which simplifies the equation to $M=M$, making the maximum value unbounded.

Comment: The question is tagged [Tag:alphametic]. What you claim as an assumption is defined by this tag.

Answer (score 3):

Since this was solved for non-distinct digits, I'm trying to get the maximum out of "MATH" with distinct digits.
So the first try is with

> M = 9. We imediately see that S needs to be 8.
>  We get
>
> ```
>   AWE +
>  8O9E =
>  9ATH
> ```

> Since the hundreds of "AWE" and "MATH" need to be the same ("A") ?this means that "O" needs to be 0 and 9+W must not go over 10 so we don't get a 1 to carry. this means that W is also 0. So this does not work.

So my seconds try is with

> M = 8 so S = 7
>
> ```
>   AWE +
>  7O8E =
>  8ATH
> ```

> Now we try to maximize "A". Let's go with the obvious 9. This means again O = 0 or 1 and we get.
>
> ```
>   9WE +
>  708E =
>  89TH
> ```

> now 8+w must not go over 10 so w = 1 ('cuz 0 is taken). But this leads to T being either 9 or 0 (if E+E go over 10) but both 9 and 0 are taken.
>  continuing to maximize A.... so 9 does not work, 8 and 7 are taken by M and S....so 6
>
> ```
>   6WE +
>  7O8E =
>  86TH
> ```

> if O = 0 we end up with a similar contradiction as above, so lets try with o = 9 and w+8+(a possible carry from E+E) go over 10.
>
> ```
>   6WE +
>  798E =
>  86TH
> ```

> Now lets maximize T in math. 9, 8, 7, 6 are taken so lets go with 5.  This  means W+8+(possible carry from E+E) = 15. This leads to W being either 6 or 7 but they are already taken by A and S.
>  so lets go with T = 4. This means W+8+(possible carry from E+E) = 14. So W is 5 or 6. 6 is taken by A so W = 5.
>
> ```
>   65E +
>  798E =
>  864H
> ```

> NOw E+ E needs to go over 10. but all of 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 are taken.  So this is no good.
>  so let's try with T = 3.  This means W+8+(possible carry from E+E) = 13. So W is 4 or 5.
>  If w = 5
>
> ```
>   65E +
>  798E =
>  863H
> ```

> E+E should be below 10. E cannot be 0 because H would be 0. SO it can be 1, 2, 4 (3 is taken by T). If it's 4 then H would be 8 which is taken by M.
>  It works with both 1 and 2 but to maximize "math" we go with 2.

So the final result:

> ```
>   652 +
>  7982 =
>  8634
> ```